# Redis socket closed unexpectedly nodejs

Tags: node.js, redis, node-redis

I am frequently getting warning "**Redis socket closed unexpectedly**" inside Node.js

Code Sample

**redis-config.js**

```
const config = require('./config');
const redis = require('redis');
const cache = redis.createClient({
  url: config.redisip + ":" + config.redisport,
  password: config.redisauth,
  socket: {
    reconnectStrategy: 10
  }
});
cache.on('error', function (error) {
  console.log('\n' + error);
});
cache.on('reconnecting', () => {
  console.log('Redis reconnecting');
});
cache.on('connect', () => {
   console.log('Redis connected');
});
cache.on('ready', () => {
   console.log('Redis ready');
});
cache.on('end', () => {
   console.log('Redis connection closed');
});
module.exports = cache;
```

**redis-middleware.js :**

```
 const redisclient = require('./redisClient');
 const cache = {
    redisMiddleware: async (req, res, next) => {
       try {
           if (!redisclient.isOpen) await redisclient.connect();
       } catch (err) {
           console.log("{'message':" + err + "}", "error");
       }
    }
 }
```

Please help to resolve issue.

Comment: How can we reproduce the issue?

Comment: I'd guess the redis server, or the connection you're using, is flaky.

Comment: In order to help here we'll need to know more about your redis server configuration.  For example, what is the `maxclients` directive set to in `redis.conf`?

Comment: @LinDu just copy on local and check

Comment: Additionally can you provide any of the logs?

Comment: @SimonPrickett we are using default configuration of azure

Comment: @LucasHendren we are getting "socket closed unexpectedly" after that reconnecting log